# resize parent block accordion to resizing child block

Tags: html, css

I have a child div block and a parent div block. Child block changes its size, but parent block has the same size. How can I resize parent block accordion to child block?

HTML:

```
<div class="about_me">
    <p>About me<img class="pencil" src="assets/pencil.png" alt=""></p>
    <div class="about_me_content">
            some information..
    </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.about_me

        position: relative
        top: 90px   
        width: 981px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <style>
.about_me{


     position: relative;
        top: 90px ;  
        width: 981px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        }

  .about_me_content{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid 

blue;



  }      
</style>

<body>
<div class="about_me">

    <p>About me<img class="pencil" src="assets/pencil.png" alt=""></p>
    <div class="about_me_content">
            some information..
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

if the width of the child block is in % it will be flexible as you want.

Comment: i added border color to identify or differentiate the two classes